# How to test the regex to replace 0x1B character (ASCII escape character) in textarea or work notes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am testing a feature which may contain ASCII escape character in the work notes field and I want to replace all occurrence of ASCII escape character with an empty string (i.e I want to remove it) before storing it in the database.

How to test the 0x1b character?

Here is the code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Regex to replace 0x1B character (ASCII escape character)</h2>

<button id="btn">Replace</button>

<p id="demo">Be the change that you wish to see in the world. ― Mahatma Gandhi</p>

<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var txt = str.replace(/0x1B/g,'');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me on how to simulate the ASCII escape character?

Comment: Note: Both HTML and JavaScript use the Unicode character set, not ASCII. JavaScript uses the UTF-16 character encoding. `'\u001B'` is the one UTF-16 code unit for the Unicode codepoint you wish to replace. (`'\x1B'` would work too but it represents an ISO 8859-1 codepoint that gets transcoded to UTF-16 and so is unnecessarily indirect.)

Comment: Thank you, Cid, for the clarification. Got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\x1B` in your regex to check the hexadecimal character `0x1B`

In exemple, if you want to find the character `B` that has the hexadecimal value `0x42`, you can use `/\x42/`

[Test it yourself](https://regex101.com/r/ZHOqMc/1)